# Install openfire in AWS server (centOS server)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, centos, xmpp, openfire

**Steps to install openfire in linux**

- RHEL Based (Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS, Fedora, openSUSE *kind 
  of*, etc)
- sudo yum install openjdk-7-jre wget wget
- http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloadServlet?filename=openfire/openfire-3.8.2-1.i386.rpm
- sudo rpm -ivh openfire-3.8.2-1.i386.rpm

can anyone help me out I have followed the above step and my server is RHEL Based

1. RHEL Based (Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS, Fedora, openSUSE *kind of*, etc)
2. sudo yum install openjdk-7-jre wget
3. wget http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloadServlet?filename=openfire/openfire-3.8.2-1 .i386.rpm
4. sudo rpm -ivh openfire-3.8.2-1.i386.rpm
5. sudo /etc/init.d/openfire status

**it says openfire is not running.**

but im not able to start openfire server.
Please help me,

Thank you.

Comment: While searching for solution for my problem I came across this website link which solved my problem.
http://rricketts.com/install-openfire-3-8-1-on-centos-6-4-x86_64/

Answer (score 2):

I had some troubles with Openfire (rel. 3.10.2) setup on a CentOS server and I had to modify the script used to start/stop the service:

In order to avoid that Openfire tries to use its specific Java version and instead forcing it to use the system `JAVA_HOME`, we commented lines 90-93 of */opt/openfire/bin/openfire.sh*:

```
# Override with bundled jre if it exists.
#if [ -f "$OPENFIRE_HOME/jre/bin/java" ]; then
#             JAVA_HOME="$OPENFIRE_HOME/jre"
#             JAVACMD="$OPENFIRE_HOME/jre/bin/java"
#fi
```

and lines 65-79 of */etc/init.d/openfire*:

```
# Attempt to locate java installation.
#if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
#             if [ -d "${OPENFIRE_HOME}/jre" ]; then
#                             JAVA_HOME="${OPENFIRE_HOME}/jre"
#             elif [ -d "/etc/alternatives/jre" ]; then
#                             JAVA_HOME="/etc/alternatives/jre"
#             else
#                             jdks=`ls -r1d /usr/java/j*`
#                             for jdk in $jdks; do
#                                            if [ -f "${jdk}/bin/java" ]; then
#                                                            JAVA_HOME="$jdk"
#                                                            break
#                                            fi
#                             done
#             fi
#fi
```

I hope this could help.